# Unstable Arduino Web Server

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I have been trying to setup a web server using Arduino. I have an UNO and a HanRun HR91105A I got off the internet, and I am using a modified version of the WebServer example to test my code. It did in fact work at first. But after setting up port forwarding, the connection suddenly became unstable. It connects and works for a few minutes, then suddenly I can't even ping it. Trying to ping the Arduino results in request time out.  Research online suggests 2 possibilities:

1.) All the RAM is used up
2.) Ethernet shield is faulty

Below is my code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0x44, 0x00, 0x10, 0x20, 0x8C, 0x0A
};
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,90);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(8081);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
    // listen for incoming clients
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      Serial.println("new client");
      // an http request ends with a blank line
      boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
      while (client.connected()) {
        if (client.available()) {
          char c = client.read();
          Serial.write(c);
          // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
          // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
          // so you can send a reply
          if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
            // send a standard http response header
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");  
            client.println("Refresh: 2");
            client.println();
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
//-----------------Type in outputs below-------------------------------------
            client.println("<html>");
            client.print("Hello World!");
            client.print("<p id='Header'>");
            client.print("Sensor Data");
            client.println("</p>");
            client.print("<p id='Pressure'>");
            client.print("Pressure:");
            client.println("</p>");
            client.print("<p id='Acceleration'>");
            client.print("Acceleration:");
            client.println("</p>");
            client.println("<br /)");
            client.println("</html>");
            break;
//-----------------End of outputs--------------------------------------------
              }

            if (c == '\n') {
              // you're starting a new line
              currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } else if (c != '\r') {
              // you've gotten a character on the current line
              currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }
          }
        }
        // give the web browser time to receive the data
        delay(1);
        // close the connection:
        client.stop();
        Serial.println("client disconnected");
      }
    }
```

Additionally, the arduino does have a static IP, so I'm pretty sure it is not an issue of DHCP lease expiry.

I highly suspect that the shield is faulty as it gets very hot while in operation. Plus it IS a knockoff. But I can't dismiss the possibility that my coding is just inefficient as I am not very experienced. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Your Arduino will opperate unpredictably when RAM is not enough.
In this code, there are many constant string. you should store those strings in FLASH memory to save RAM. In order to to so, use F() macro. For example. 
***client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));***

If your program is big, I recommend to use the shield that equips an embedded web sever (e.g PHPoC Shield)